# Problem while adding field dynamically using js

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form In which there is a add button which clones and append  three input field of a form (In these three fields, two are simple text field but third field contains the option to choose and these options are fetched from a database table) when I append the filed using Add button it append the field below but I am not able to insert data on the option field of appended row. Suppose i have appended three row  and I tried to choose the value on the third row it will change the value of first row and third row remains blank. I am new to js. I'm posting code of js. If php code required i will also post that later on.

```
var max = 4;
var count = 1;
$(function(){
    $('#addMore').on('click', function() {
            if(count <= max ){
              var data = $("#tb tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
              data.find("input").val('');
              debugger;
              data.find("input")[0].value=++count;
            }else{
             alert("Sorry!! Can't add more than five samples at a time !!");
           }
              
     });
     $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
         var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if(trIndex>1) {
             $(this).closest("tr").remove();
           } else {
             alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");

     var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        if(trIndex>1) {
         $(this).closest("tr").remove();
         count--;
         
         // get all the rows in table except header.
         $('#tb tr:not(.tr-header)').each(function(){
         $(this).find('td:first-child input').val(this.rowIndex);
         })
           }
      });
});
```

My form looks like this

[image: FORM]

Comment: You need to show us a proper [mre] of this. Just by looking at a screenshot of your rendered form, we can not tell what exactly the HTML looks like.

Comment: @04FS this is the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213593/java-script-problem-while-inserting-data-in-form

Comment: Please make your questions self-contained, instead of just referring to other questions. Btw., is that a different user, or are you asking under multiple accounts?

Comment: @04FS he is my friend we both are working on the same project he previously asked that one